# Загрузка изображения в профиль

Tags: php, mvc

Пробую сделать загрузку изображения пользователя на аву,но столкнулся с проблемой. Выводится не картинка,а сам массив с данными о изображении внутри которые он содержит : Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => unnamed.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => W:\userdata\php_upload\php4F17.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 52308 ) ) 1

То есть я так понимаю сама передача осуществляется,но нет вывода самой картинки и нет добавления ее имени в  БД . Зашел в тупик из-за нехватки опыта.Прошу помощи.Спасибо

```
//dashboard 

            <p><?=$_FILES['file']?></p>
            <form action="/user/dashboard" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="file" name="file">
       <input type="submit" value="Загрузить файл!" class="btn btn-info">
          </form>



//UserModel


    public function can_upload($file){
                  $sql = 'INSERT INTO users(image) VALUES(:image)';
                  $query = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
                  $sth->execute(['image' => $file['name']]);
                // если имя пустое, значит файл не выбран
                  if($file['name'] == '')
                  return 'Вы не выбрали файл.';


                // if($file['size'] > 50000)
                //   return 'Файл слишком большой.';

                // разбиваем имя файла по точке и получаем массив
                $getMime = explode('.', $file['name']);
                // нас интересует последний элемент массива - расширение
                $mime = strtolower(end($getMime));
                // объявим массив допустимых расширений
                $types = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'jpeg');

                // если расширение не входит в список допустимых - return
                if(!in_array($mime, $types))
                  return 'Недопустимый тип файла.';

                return true;
                }

                public  function make_upload($file){
                // формируем уникальное имя картинки: случайное число и name
                $name = mt_rand(0, 10000) . $file['name'];
       
               move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], 'public/img');
                }

//User

  public function pic(){
          // если была произведена отправка формы
              if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
                // проверяем, можно ли загружать изображение
                $check = can_upload($_FILES['file']);

                if($check === true){
                  // загружаем изображение на сервер
                  make_upload($_FILES['file']);
                  echo "<strong>Файл успешно загружен!</strong>";
                }
                else{
                  // выводим сообщение об ошибке
                  echo "<strong>$check</strong>";
                }
              }



        }
```

Comment: в плейсхолдере потерял двоеточие $sth->execute([':image' => $file['name']]); и вообще сначала проверяют наличие файла, а потом делают запрос к бд

Answer (score 0):

Если вкратце, то выгляди так. По сути каждая функция возвращает результат true/false. например ты ожидаешь что файл загрузится move_uploaded_file(), но файл может не загрузиться по нескольким причинам - не хватает прав на запись в папку, папки не существует и тд. То же самое и с базой данных - запись может добавиться в таблицу, а может и не добавиться, может там настроена уникальность имен файлов. Да, очень много проверок в итоге.

**dashboard.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/so/dashboard.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Загрузить файл!" class="btn btn-info">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**dashboard.php**

```
class FileUpload {

    private $file;

    public function __construct($file) {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    public function upload() {

        if ($this->canUpload()) {
            $result = $this->doUpload();
            return $result;
        }

        return false;
    }


    protected function canUpload() {

        //see http://htmlbook.ru/html/value/mime
        $types = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/bmp', 'image/gif'];

        if (!in_array($this->file['type'], $types))
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    protected function doUpload() {

        $name = mt_rand(0, 10000) . '_' . $this->file['name'];
        $this->file['name'] = $name;
        $upload_dir = ROOT_DIR . '/uploads/' . $name;

        $result = move_uploaded_file($this->file['tmp_name'], $upload_dir);

        if ($result) {
            $this->insert();
            $this->view();
        }

        return $result;
    }


    protected function insert() {
        //$sql = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO users (image) VALUES (:image)';
        //$sth = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
        //$result = $sth->execute([':image' => $this->file['name']]);
        //return $result;

    }

    protected function view() {
        $url = DOMAIN . '/uploads/' . $this->file['name'];
        echo '<img src="' . $url . '" width="300px" />';
        echo '<a href="../so/dashboard.html">взад</a>';

    }
}


const DOMAIN = '/so/';
const ROOT_DIR = __DIR__;

if (isset($_FILES['file']) && !empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    $f = new FileUpload($_FILES['file']);
    $f->upload();

} else {
    echo 'файл пока не был выбран <a href="../so/dashboard.html">взад</a>';
}
```